# Can I use my brokerage accounts and trading as my job evidence?

Tags: united-states, banking, trading, credit, financial-advisor

I live in the US and have some brokerage accounts and I have income from trading online. I also don't have another job. Can I use my income and trading history when I want to apply for a loan or finance something or get a new credit card to showing them and say this is my job?

Comment: be aware you'll need on the order of three **if not six or more** years evidence of this, AND, the only evidence is tax returns. if you don't have at least about five years of tax returns showing how much money you made from trading, really just forget it

Answer (score 3):

If you've been self-employed at personal online stock trading, then absolutely say it's been your job.

Of course, they'll certainly ask you for proof (like 1099 forms, extracts from two or three 1040 forms, etc), just like any other self-employed person.

Answer (score -2):

To answer your specific question,

> Can I use my brokerage accounts as my job evidence ...

No, only IRS tax returns (absolute minimum three years)